# Print format using NumPy in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I want to create a 2d dimensional array in NumPy of size `128x2` and store in it long integers (each integer has 128-bit size).

**CODE:**

```
keys = np.zeros(shape=(128, 2))
for i in range(0, 128):

    key1 = random.randrange(1 << 127, 1 << 128)
    key2 = random.randrange(1 << 127, 1 << 128)

    keys[i, 0] = key1
    keys[i, 1] = key2

print(keys)
```

A random key has the following output:

```
212325597117085680729458082297541802625
```

However when I print my keys array I got the following output:

**OUTPUT:**

```
[[  3.24916136e+38   1.88464325e+38]
 [  3.01375156e+38   2.73451722e+38]
 [  1.85204001e+38   2.47016718e+38]
 [  1.85813038e+38   2.66817805e+38]
 [  1.93774249e+38   2.62902937e+38]
 [  2.77003163e+38   2.13490918e+38]
 [  1.92502885e+38   3.28965325e+38]
 [  3.03869869e+38   2.27308256e+38]
 [  2.97958126e+38   2.50477741e+38]
 [  1.82747542e+38   2.17062238e+38]
 [  2.59264124e+38   3.17242510e+38]
 [  2.43152125e+38   3.33742346e+38]
etc
```

How do I print the keys in their original format?

Comment: `numpy` doesn't have a 128-bit integer type (at least, not on any platform I've used). How exactly do you want to store them in your array? As Python objects? As strings? Your current code is using double-precision floats (64-bits divided between the sign, mantissa and exponent) which will lose quite a few of the least significant bits.

Comment: Have you had a look at numpy.set_printoptions() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues you're having with your code.

The first is that your using an inappropriate `dtype` for your array of long integers. The default `dtype` of the array returned by `np.zeros` is `float64`, which means you're going to be losing a lot of precision when saving your integers to that array. It doesn't matter how you go about formatting the output afterwards, the data simply isn't there any more.

Unfortunately, `numpy` doesn't have a built-in 128-bit integer type. You'll have to decide for yourself how to store it. A composite `dtype` with two `uint64`s might work (though you'd have to do your own carrying between the numbers whenever you do math operations on them). Alternatively, if you don't need to do any math on the long integers in the array, you could use a string `dtype`. A third option would be to use `object` as the `dtype` and let it use Python's normal `int`s (which support unlimited precision math, but with much worse performance than hardware-supported `numpy` types).

The second issue is formatting the integers for printing (what you were actually asking about). You can call `np.set_printoptions` to specify a formatting approach for your array, but this will only help if you are using a `dtype` natively supported by `numpy`. If you're using some other type, you may need to write a loop over the array contents and print the items out appropriately as you go.